# Why does 0th layer mean for reduce_mean give wrong averages?

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, layer, tensor

I have 3rd layer array here

```
t = tf.constant([[[1., 1., 1.], [2., 2., 2.]], [[3., 3., 3.], [4., 4., 4.]]])
tf.reduce_mean(t,0)
```

I thought the 0th layer mean would be 1.5 and 3.5. However, it is giving me 2 and 3. Can someone help to explain what's happening here?

```
<tf.Tensor: id=8966, shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Also, what I do not understand is why doesn't

```
t = tf.constant([[[1., 1., 1.], [2., 2., 2.]], [[3., 3., 3.], [4., 4., 4.]]])
tf.reduce_mean(t,2)
```

Give out an answer as

```
[[[1.],[2.]],
 [[3.],[4.]]]
```

? It gives out an answer as

```
<tf.Tensor: id=9014, shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Where did the 2nd layer of [] go?

Which part of layer am I not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a depiction of how `tf.reduce_mean` works on `axis=0`.

[image]

You have a `(2,2,3)` array. `tf.reduce_mean(t, 0)` produces a `(2,3)` array by squashing the array (by taking mean) on `axis=0` as shown. The same you can visualize for any other dimension.

Whenever you do a `reduction` operation on an axis that axis disappears (actually becomes `1`). If you want to keep that dimension just set `tf.reduce_mean(t, 0, keepdims=True)`.